# Searching for Weblogic class: MessageLoggerRegistryListener

Tags: java, weblogic, noclassdeffounderror, weblogic12c

Currently I'm working with `EJB` services running on Weblogic 12c Server. When I write a `JUnit` test to call `EJB` services, an error appears with:

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   weblogic/i18n/logging/MessageLoggerRegistryListener

Anyone knows where is this class from? I googled it but got no result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This class can be found in the /wlserver/modules/features/weblogic.server.merged.jar and in the /wlserver/server/lib/wlclient.jar files.

Answer (score 0):

Additionally if you are doing this in a maven project, and you're using the [Oracle Maven repository](http://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1213/core/MAVEN/config_maven_repo.htm#MAVEN9010), you can use

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.oracle.weblogic</groupId>
    <artifactId>wlclient</artifactId>
    <version>12.1.3-0-0</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

Set WL_HOME in your environment variable correctly:

Variable name: WL_HOME

Variable value: 
your weblogic 12c installation path like: C:/Oracle/Middleware/Oracle_Home/wlserver/server